# non-smooth fonts in Fedora's gnome

Tags: fedora, gnome, fonts

[image: screenshot]

I don't know is that only my problem or not but I have a little eyestrain when using Fedora (19) with Gnome 3(.8) compared to Ubuntu, Linux mint or Windows.

Maybe the problem is caused by font rendering or anti aliasing or even the fonts themselves. I think the fonts are sharp. I cannot explain that but I believe that it's different from Ubuntu.

Comment: Is the resolution the same? If the resolutions match between the two it might be font scaling.

Comment: @Tim Yes, My resolution is 1366*768

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem on my Arch/Gnome setup. To fix it, I installed `gnome-tweak-tool`. Go to the Fonts tab and set Hinting to None. Play around with the settings till you find a setting that suits you.

Comment: This answer helped me. But I did set it to slight.